# Mongodb update new position for exist item in an aray and add new if not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to implement the SearchHistory for my app using NodeJs with MongoDb.

My array returned: 
SearchHistory = [“food”, “service”,”car”]

I want to swap the position of the item in this array to the first position if i insert the same String. And will add new to the first position if it is not existing in the array.

For example: If I search “car” in my app, the array will be returned as
SearchHistory = [“car”, “food”, “service”]

And will be: SearchHistory = [“book”, “car”, “food”, “service”] if I insert book in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SearchHistory = ["car", "food", "service"]

newSearch = "book"

searchExistsIndex = SearchHistory.indexOf(newSearch)

if (searchExists != -1) {
    SearchHistory.splice(searchExists, 1)
    SearchHistory.splice(0, 0, newSearch)

} else {
    SearchHistory.splice(0, 0, newSearch)
}
```

The newSearch variable is the new search what you said. 
The searchExistsIndex looks if the newSearch string is already in the list. If not it will return -1 and it will only add the newSearch string to the front of the array. If it returns anything else than -1 it will remove it from the list first and then it will add the newSearch to the front of the list.

I think this is the easiest way. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I hope this answer helped you with your problem.

Comment: DIdn't my answer work or help you? Why have you marked it unanswered?